# Gª surname—meaning?

Tags: abreviaturas

“Emilio Biurrun Gª de Galdeano” is a name on a gravestone.

Am I safe in assuming Garcia? There is more than one G___a apellido elsewhere in the cemetery.  But Jose Iglesias Garcia Arenal is frequently called Jose Iglesias Gª-Arenal on web pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is most likely García. Abbreviations of surnames are not standard but, according to [Wikilengua](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Abreviaturas_de_nombres_propios), sometimes the first surname is abbreviated when it is very common and the second surname is also given. This is the case in both your examples: "Gª de Galdeano" and "Gª-Arenal". Wikilengua explicitly gives the example of "García: Gª".

This also agrees with my own experience: I have seen García abbreviated as "Gª", but not other surnames like "Guerra".

Comment: I would even say that it would be most surprising to find an example of *Gª* not meaning *García*. Same as *Mª* in a name is always *María*.